# Laptop fails to open desktop after upgrade to 23.10

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, xfce, bug-reporting

Sorry, the information here is going to be basic as I am on my Windows OS as the xUBUNTU will not open since my upgrade.

I upgraded yesterday, following the usual instructions. Was straightforward and only two ineteruptions to ask me if I wanted to keep the same IME config and the same GRUB config. I ket the later and went with the new former. After a reboot the laptop gets the GRUB menu and I chose the new image and started to boot as normal. The logo appeared, and then it went in to a command line for me to enter my username and password.

I can not fix things. I've tried a CD, but that won't load. I've tried looking at the logs but there is so much there it is meaningless to me and I can't paste here...
I tried using the recovery and tried to fix broken packages. I noted a lot of NVIDIA drivers with dependecies unmet, along with many other things.

I believe not all the required drivers are installed, that NVIDIA in particular.  I do not think all the directories are mounting and MAYBE even a whole hard drive.  But I don't know how to check or fix.

I checked within the Windows 11 OS and the two hard drives appear, and all the partitions.  Two are NTFS and can be opened by Windows and work.  The others can not but state HEALTHY.  However in the Ubuntu terminal when I type sudo umount -a I get errors.  UUID not found as an example.  Not sure how to mod fstab in a terminal

MSI GF63 Thin 9RCX 15.6" FHD Laptop Computer Intel Core i7 9750H 256GB SSD GTX 1050 Ti

As I can not get in to report I can not send command responses. I have to photo them and paste here. See link.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/photos/shar...Zto2zVkKoFoLK8

=============================================================

UPDATE  Issue found and Solution:

I was randomly playing, and I got a warning that the "Display Environment" was missing. Double-checked what it meant and as soon as I noted xUbuntu and XFCE, I rebooted in to "recovery". Control+D, Selected "Turn on Network", then "Root" and
Code:

sudo apt-get update

,
Code:

sundo apt-get clean

,
Code:

sudo apt-get autoclean

,
Code:

sudo pat-get autoremove

,
Code:

sudo apt-get install xfce4

and then
Code:

sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

That latter threw up a choice, "Display Manager"; "gdm" or "LightDim"? I chose GDM, but not sure of the differences, but I do recall that a few years ago one gave issues. So need to recall which and learn how to switch. After completing the installation, I then did,
Code:

sudo apt-get install gnome-software

. None of these threw up errors, other than xfce was already installed.

This must mean that **during the upgrade the XUbuntu was removed and not replaced, or at least it was not configured to switch to an alternative**.  This is clearly a bug. The laptop was rebooted. Took a while, but soon I had my log-in again, with chooser. Although a different appearance. Logged in, a bit slow. But after a couple of reboots it has sped up and all is right with the world.

Thank you to all those who looked in.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: FAILED update/upgrade is getting common again.  When I started with Ubuntu in 2007 it happened every upgrade, almost, but by 2013 that seemed to stop and they've been almost flawless since.  Now I have a PC that isn't working and in for repair since July and now this one.  I see lots of people having issues.  Seems an issue with the release process/quality control.  So what does one back up and how?  Note too that I can't even get in, only at commandline.

Comment: More information.  Control + D and looking at the journal these items are highlighted.  May shed some light.   https://www.amazon.co.uk/photos/share/LSF1UCvypJh3tA1skfWZ89PIlQewv4uIn0JzioZ9J73

Comment: If you can terminal, what is the result of `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` please?